# Number of arithmetic operations (multiplications and divisions) needed for the Jordan elimination method

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

I have an assignment to find the number of operations (only multiplications and divisions) needed to solve $N \times N$ linear equation while using Jordan Elimination method. I thought about it in two different ways but I'm not sure if my work is right.

Suppose that that the augumented matrix where I need to apply the Jordan elimination is:

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
a_{11}& \cdots \quad \cdots \quad \cdots \quad \cdots &a_{1n}&a_{1,n+1}\\
a_{21}& \cdots \quad \cdots \quad \cdots \quad \cdots &a_{2n}&a_{2,n+1}\\
\vdots&  \quad \quad \quad & \vdots&\vdots\\
\vdots&  \quad \quad \quad & \vdots&\vdots\\
a_{n1}& \cdots \quad \cdots \quad \cdots \quad \cdots &a_{nn}&a_{n,n+1}\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

### Step 1: for the $1^{st}$ row

Normalization of this row requires $n+1$ divisions since there is $n+1$ elements in the first row that I have to divide by $a_{11}$ and reduction requires $(n-1) (n+1)$ operations since I have to multiply each element of the $1^{st}$ row by $a_{i1}, i \neq 1$ (before subtracting the result from the $i^{th}$ row respectively but I'm not counting the additions/subtractions). There is $n -1$ rows where I have to do this and in each row there is $n+1$ elements or $n+1$ columns. Therefore, the total operations for the $1^{st}$ step is:
$$(n+1) + (n-1)(n+1)$$

Note that I've thought about the reduction in another way which gave me a different answer. I know for a fact that all the elements below $a_{11}$ will be zero so there is no need to multiply these elements by $a_{11}$ and I can just put zero right away. Therefore, I still have to do the reduction on $n-1$ rows but only on $n$ columns. Thus, the total number of operations if I used this method should be:

$$
(n+1) + (n-1)n
$$
At the end of this step, the matrix should look like:
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
a_{11}& \cdots \quad \cdots \quad \cdots \quad \cdots &a_{1n}&a_{1,n+1}\\
0& a_{22} \quad \cdots \quad \cdots \quad \cdots &a_{2n}&a_{2,n+1}\\
\vdots& \quad & \vdots&\vdots\\
\vdots&  \quad \quad \quad & \vdots&\vdots\\
0& a_{n2} \quad \cdots \quad \cdots \quad \cdots &a_{nn}&a_{n,n+1}\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

### Step 2: for the 2$^{nd}$ row

In this step, normalization requires $n$ divisions since I have to divide each element of the $2^{nd}$ row (except $a_{21}$ which is already zero) by $a_{22}$.

For the reduction part, I have to multiply each element of the $2^{nd}$ row (except $a_{21}$) by $a_{i2}, i \neq 2$ before subtracting. There is $n-1$ rows and $n$ columns so the number of operations for the reduction part is: $(n-1)n$ and the total number of operations for this step is:
$$
n + (n-1)n
$$

As in step 1, I know that $a_{i2}, (i \neq 2)$ will be zero in this step so I can skip the multiplication of these elements so instead of $n$ columns, I have $n-1$ columns. Therefore, the total number of operations should be:
$$
n + (n-1)(n-1)
$$

$\vdots$

### Step k: for the k$^{th}$ row

I concluded that the number of divisions in the $k^{th}$ step should be: $n-k+2$ and the number of operations in the reduction part should be either: $(n-1)(n-k+2)$ or $(n-1)(n-k+1)$ depending on my approach as stated above.

The total number of operations for the $k^{th}$ step is either:
$$
(n-k+2) + (n-1)(n-k+2)
$$

$$\mathbf{OR}$$

$$
(n-k+2) + (n-1)(n-k+1)
$$

---

---

The total number of operations of the Jordan elimination is either:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left[(n-k+2) + (n-1)(n-k+2) \right] = \frac{n^3}{2} + \frac{3n^2}{2}
$$

$$\mathbf{OR}$$

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left[(n-k+2) + (n-1)(n-k+1) \right] = \frac{n^3}{2} + \frac{n^2}{2} + n
$$

Is my work right? I hope my work will be of good help to those seeking the same answer since I didn't find much about this topic on the internet.

Comment: When normalizing a row, you only need to do $n$ divisions. For the remaining one, you are just dividing a number by itself, so the result is $1$ and does not need to be calculated. Similarly there is one less multiplication needed for every other row, as the total result for one column will always be $0$.

Comment: I thought about needing only $n$ divisions for each normalization after posting my question but thanks for pointing this out. Do you think my approach to this problem is right or is there any other modification I should do?